# THIS context in a event handler function in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I´m newbee in javascript and have some headaches.. I note that the "this" object, inside a event handler function is not the main class, like here:

```
Ext.define('App.controls.VerticalMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

setMenu: function(item) { 

    "this" here, is a "VerticalMenu"
    var theBtn = Ext.create('App.controls.VerticalMenuItem',{
        listeners: {
            onOpenClose: function(btn){
                "this" here is a "VerticalMenuItem"
            }
        }
    });
},
```

How to access the main "this" object (VerticalMenu) inside this event handler function ?

Comment: @Derek's answer is probably the best way to go since it leverages the framework.  My answer is the "standard" way to do it outside of the Ext framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J Torres's answer is one way. In Ext, depending on how you add the listener, sometimes you can specify a scope.

```
setMenu: function(item) { 

    var theBtn = Ext.create('App.controls.VerticalMenuItem',{});
    theBtn.on('openclose',function(btn){
        //what we want to do
    }, this); // Preserves the current scope of this for use inside the handler
},
```

Comment: Or `listeners: { onOpenClose: { fn: function(btn) { /* "this" have tha same value as "this" directly inside "setMenu" */ }, scope: this } }`. At least this is the ExtJs way.

Comment: TMTOWDTI. :) You can use a config object as @Prusse did, which does the same thing I did with my on function.

Answer (score 2):

Many people use "me." Example:

```
Ext.define('App.controls.VerticalMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    setMenu: function(item) { 
        var me = this;
        var theBtn = Ext.create('App.controls.VerticalMenuItem',{
            listeners: {
                onOpenClose: function(btn){
                    me.DoSomethingUseful();
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Is that an `ExtJS` thing?  In my experience **most** people use `self` or `that`.

Comment: I've seen "me" from jQuery/jQuery UI mostly.

Comment: I've never seen it before.  FWIW you need to explain _why_ that extra variable is needed.

Comment: I've seen me and that used in various places. Doesn't really matter which you use.

Comment: @Alnitak The OP pretty clearly states he understands what happens to this, thus no explanation seems to be required.

Comment: @Alnitak: the code was wrong. Haven't worked in Ext in about a year, had to go back and look up how to specify a scope.

Comment: @JTorres I disagree.  He's states he noticed that it's no longer the right object - he doesn't appear to know why.

Comment: @Alnitak Then I'm glad you provided your own answer as I feel my answer does not NEED any additional explantation as it answer's the OP's direct question.

Comment: This was my first atempt to resolve this situation. But the Derek or Prusse solution seems to be the right way.